# The image of an path connected space is connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a path connected space and $f:E\rightarrow F$ continuous and surjetive function  then $F$ is connected

Can i say : $E$ is path connected then it is connected, as $f$ is continuous $f(E)$ is connected, $f$ is surjective then $f(E)=F$ .

Thank you

Comment: The image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected. A path connected space is connected, so...

Comment: This is exactly what he wrote

Comment: @klirk Indeed. $ $

Answer (score 1):

You can even say more: let $y_1, y_2 \in F$, pick $x_1, x_2 \in E$ with $f(x_1) = y_1, f(x_2) = y_2$ by surjectivity.

Let $p: [0,1] \rightarrow E$ be a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$, i.e. $p$ is continuous and $p(0) = x_1, p(1) = x_2$. But then $f \circ p: [0,1] \rightarrow F$ is a path from $y_1$ to $y_2$: continuity is clear as both $p$ and $f$ are, and $f(p(0)) = f(x_1) = y_1, f(p(1)) = f(x_2) = y_2$.

So $F$ is even path-connected (hecne a fortiori connected as well).

A similar argument will show that all products of path-connected spaces are path-connected too.